# How to use jboss-log4j.xml in my application

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j

It is possible to use jboss-log4j.xml as configuration file for my application ?
I just want my application to log in the same place as Jboss server(console and file)...

Answer (score 2):

JBoss uses a single global log4j configuration for every application. Any calls your app makes to log4j will be routed via the config in `jboss-log4j.xml`. You should feel free to modify that file to suit your application(s) - it determines which loggers use which files.

By default, your application(s) logs will will go to the same file(s) as JBoss itself logs to.

Comment: I needed to call my class with this paramether:
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\all\conf\jboss-log4j.xml

in order for the jboss-log4j.xml properties to be considered.
And I didn't yet find a way to log in the same console jboss is logging.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use *all* the same logging rules as JBoss then you can reference your existing jboss-log4j.xml file from your app.  Otherwise, you could just copy the relevant output sections into a separate file specific to your app.  I would recommend the 2nd approach.